# SIR Model - deSolve in R. Different events at different time points

Tags: r

This is partially related to another question I have asked.
[deSolve for R - Parameterise Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793491/desolve-for-r-parameterise-events)

I'm writing an SIR Model using the deSolve package for R. The model describes transmission of an infection within a community and then allows the introduction of external events - which represent mass treatment of the whole community.

These are modelled as events that occur at specific times.
Ideally I would like to be able to have two different types of external event so that what you get is

Model Running
Time Point = X: Triggers Event A
Model Continues
Time Point = Z: Triggers Event B
etc etc

I tried using an if command so that if T=X then event = event A and if T = Z then it triggered a different event but had no joy.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Code below

```
#load deSolve

library(deSolve)

#generate an empty list for the data to be put into

simulationlist <- list()

#define the transmission model

SI1I2L <- function(t, y, parms) {

  with(as.list(c(parms,y)),{
    dS <- - Beta*S*I1 - Beta*S*I2 + treat*I1 + treat*I2 +latenttreat*L
    dI1 <- + Beta*S*I1 + Beta*S*I2 - treat*I1 -second*I1 - latent*I1
    dI2 <- + second*I1 - latent*I2 - treat*I2 + relapse*L
    dL <- +latent*I1 + latent*I2 - relapse*L - latenttreat*L

    der <- c(dS, dI1,dI2, dL)
    list(der)    
  }) 

} 

#define Total Community Treatment Parameters

eventtct <- function(t, y, parms){
  with (as.list(y),{
    S <- S + 0.95*L + 0.95*I1 + 0.95*I2
    I1 <- I1*0.05
    I2 <- I2*0.05
    L <- L*0.05
    return(c(S,I1,I2,L))
  })
}

#Set the time frame for the model
dt    <- seq(0,100,1)    

#Define the spectrum of Parameters for transmission with Min/Max values and number of variations
plist <- cbind(Beta = runif(100,min = 0.00000167, max = 0.0000043),second = runif(100,min= 0.0278,max = 0.0556),latent = runif(100,min=0.004, max=0.009), treat = runif(100, min=0.01, max =0.03),latenttreat = runif(100,min=0.004,max=0.009),relapse = runif(100,min=0.012,max=0.028))
for (i in 1:nrow(plist))
#Define the spectrum of inital values for population size

initlist <- cbind(S = runif(100,min = 110681, max = 118636),I1 = runif(100,min=798, max=2926),I2 = runif(100,min=266,max=1463),L=runif(100,min=13300, max=27930))
for (i in 1:nrow(initlist))

#run multiple simulations  
simulationlist[[i]] <- as.data.frame(lsoda(initlist[i,], dt, SI1I2L, parms=plist[i,],events = list(func = eventtct, time = c(2,12) )))
```